# Using arrays in awk to match lines

Tags: awk, text-processing

I am trying to use `awk` to match two files (file1 and file2). For each line of a column in file2 that matches file1, I would like the command to print out the second column in file1.

I have looked at several of the solutions here and have found something that worked (partly), but *I don't understand how it works.*

`awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{print a[$1]}' file1 file2 >> output`

Here is an example of the input:

```
#File1
0_1   apple
0_2   mango
0_3   banana
...
3_1   durian
3_4   dragonfruit
3_20  pear
```

```
#File2
0_1   3_1
0_1   3_1
0_2   3_4
0_3   3_20
```

The awk command above returns the result I want when I am matching the first column of File2 to File1.

```
#Output
apple
apple
mango
banana
```

So naturally I adjusted the line a little to do the same for the second column in File2.

`awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $2 in a{print a[$1]}' file1 file2 >> output`

But I receive the exact same results as above, when I would be expecting:

```
#Expected output
durian
durian
dragonfruit
pear
```

To make things worse, I get the desired output when I do this:

`awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} $1 in a{print a[$2]}' file1 file2 >> output`

Could someone explain to me the logic behind this (assigning values to arrays) or did something went wrong elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please go through following explanation of code used by you. It may help you to understand array concept.

```
awk '                      ##Starting awk program from here.
NR==FNR{                   ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE once first Input_file named file1 is being read.
  a[$1]=$2                 ##Creating an array named a whose index is $1 of current line and value is $2(2nd field) of current line.
  next                     ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                          ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR condition here.
$2 in a{                   ##Checking condition(which will be executed only when 2nd Input_file named file2 is being read.
  print a[$1]              ##Now printing value of array a whose index is $1 of current line.
}                          ##Closing BLOCK for $2  in a condition here.
' file1 file2 >> output    ##Mentioning Input_file names and placing output into output file here.
```

***Additional explanation on Array's concept:***

- ***What does `a[$1]=$2` do?:*** It means we are creating an array named a whose index(by which any item is being recognized) and its value is $2(2nd field of current line).
- ***Example of `a[$1]=$2`:*** Let's take an example of `0_1   apple` from 1st Input_file where array will be stored as `a[0_1]=apple`, as explained above its index is 0_1 and value is apple.
- ***What does `$2 in a` condition do?:*** This statements is actually a condition which checks if $2 of current line is coming inside array a(off course it checks all indexes of array a and compare this string with them if they are matching or not) if any match found then print the value of array a whose value is `a[$1]`

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, thank you for the detailed answer; I would definitely break them down the next time when I try to understand an awk command. I would just like to clarify one more question: What would `print a[$2]` mean, when no `a[$2]` has been assigned? It does not seem like it would refer directly to the value assigned to the array earlier, and I am quite puzzled by the different set of output it gave from `$1 in a` or `$2 in a` commands.